# How do I make a calculation reference table in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to html and I need help with creating a calculation reference table in html. It should look something like this:

[Calculation reference table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5btKF.png)

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function squareIt(x){
        document.write (x * x);
    }
    function divideIt(x){
        document.write(1 / x);
    }
    function sqrtIt(x){
        document.write(Math.sqrt(x));
    }
    document.write("<table>");
        for (var a=1; a < 6; a++) {
            document.write("<tr>" + a);
        for (var b=1; b < 2; b++) {
            document.write("<td>"+squareIt(a)+"</td>");
            document.write("<td>"+divideIt(a)+"</td>");
            document.write("<td>"+sqrtIt(a)+"</td>");
        }
        document.write("</tr>");
        }
    document.write("</table>");
    </script>
</head>
```

I am unable to make the values fit into the table as per the picture. Any advice on how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: A function should return something in your case, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

your function must be `return` value for use in `document.wrire` or you call your function out of document.write 
i edit  your Script

```js
 function squareIt(x){
       return (x * x);
    }
    function divideIt(x){
        return(1 / x);
    }
    function sqrtIt(x){
        return (Math.sqrt(x));
    }
    document.write("<table>");
      document.write("<tr><td>x</td><td>x2</td><td>1/x</td><td>sqrt(x)</td></tr>")
        for (var a=1; a < 6; a++) {
            document.write("<tr>" );
            document.write("<td>"+a+"</td>")
            document.write("<td>"+squareIt(a)+"</td>");
            document.write("<td>"+divideIt(a)+"</td>");
            document.write("<td>"+sqrtIt(a)+"</td>");
        
        document.write("</tr>");
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
  table{
  width:400px;
  }
  table,td{
   border:1px solid black;
  }
  td{
    width:25%;
    text-align:center;
  }
</style>

   
</head>
<body>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A design error in the code you've written is that a nested loop is the wrong solution for this. There is no "y" in this task. Only x. And everything else is known and not suitable to handle with a second loop.

So make your one and only loop to iterate through the various values of X. And then specifically code each of the three uses of x (and everything else they need) inside that loop.

Meaning:

```
   // Build HTML for start of table.
   // For loop through x values.
      // start of a row
      // cell for x value
      // cell for x^2
      // cell for 1/x
      // cell for sqrt(x)
      // end of row
   // end of loop
   // end of table HTML
```

Good luck!